# Why Response No Resource found when MockMvc apply Spring Security (OAuth2)

Tags: spring, kotlin, testing, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am writing test with `MockMvc` and Spring Security.

so I maid `MockMvc` instance and apply spring security like this:

```kotlin
@BeforeEach
fun setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
            .build()

}
```

And I Add Annotation on test method - [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/method.html#test-method-withsecuritycontext)

```kotlin
@Test
@WithCustomOAuth2User(email = "test@example.com")
fun test() {
    val post = mockMvc.post("/vocabulary") {
        cookie(Cookie("SESSION", "test"))
    }

    post
        .andExpect { status { isCreated() } }
    }
}
```

WithCustomOAuth2User.kt

```kotlin
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContext

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@WithSecurityContext(factory = CustomOAuth2UserSecurityContextFactory::class)
annotation class WithCustomOAuth2User(
    val email: String,
    val providerId: String = "google",
)
```

CustomOAuth2UserSecurityContextFactory.kt

```kotlin
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextFactory

class CustomOAuth2UserSecurityContextFactory : WithSecurityContextFactory<WithCustomOAuth2User> {

    override fun createSecurityContext(annotation: WithCustomOAuth2User): SecurityContext {
        val context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext()
        val principal = DefaultOAuth2User(
            emptyList(),
            mapOf("email" to annotation.email),
            "email",
        )

        val authentication: Authentication = OAuth2AuthenticationToken(
            principal,
            principal.authorities,
            annotation.providerId,
        )
        context.authentication = authentication

        return context
    }
}
```

But It test fails http status code 404...

**Can you help me find what part is lacking or missing?**

full test code is here:

```kotlin
@Tag("restdocs")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [VocabularyController::class])
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = [
        SecurityConfig::class,
        CustomOAuth2UserService::class,
    ],
)
class VocabularyControllerTest2 {
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var context: WebApplicationContext

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var filterChain: FilterChainProxy

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(springSecurity(filterChain))
            .build()
    }

    @Test
    @WithCustomOAuth2User(email = "test@example.com")
    fun test() {
        given(userRepository.findByEmail(anyString()))
            .willReturn(Optional.of(User.createFromEmail("test@example.com")))

        val resultActions = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/vocabulary")
                .with(csrf()),
        )

        println(resultActions.andReturn().response.errorMessage)

        resultActions.andExpect(status().isCreated())
    }
}
```

> this is additional codes - spring security, custom oauth2 service...

SecurityConfig.kt

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(val customOAuth2UserService: CustomOAuth2UserService) {

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        // ...

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authorize ->
                authorize.requestMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .oauth2Login { oauthLoginConfigurer ->
                oauthLoginConfigurer.redirectionEndpoint {
                    it.baseUri("/login/oauth2/code/*")
                }
                oauthLoginConfigurer.userInfoEndpoint {
                    it.userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                }
            }

        return http.build()
    }

}
```

CustomOAuth2UserService

```kotlin
@Component
class CustomOAuth2UserService(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val httpSession: HttpSession,
) : OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {

    override fun loadUser(userRequest: OAuth2UserRequest?): OAuth2User {
        val delegate = DefaultOAuth2UserService()
        val oAuth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest)

        val email = oAuth2User.attributes["email"] as String
        val user = this.userRepository.findByEmailOrNull(email) ?: run {
            val user = User.createFromEmail(email)
            this.userRepository.save(user)
        }

        httpSession.setAttribute("userId", user.id)

        val userNameAttributesName =
            userRequest!!.clientRegistration!!.providerDetails!!.userInfoEndpoint!!.userNameAttributeName
        val registrationId = userRequest.clientRegistration?.registrationId as String
        val oAuthAttributes = OAuthAttributes.of(registrationId, userNameAttributesName, oAuth2User.attributes)

        return DefaultOAuth2User(
            emptyList(),
            oAuth2User.attributes,
            oAuthAttributes.userNameAttributesName,
        )
    }
}
```

- when remove mockMvc apply spring security, it success test
- when add `@WithCustomOAuth2User` annotation, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication is set to annotation specified infomation.

Comment: You provided with quite some info, but still, some parts are missing to reproduce (like the tested controller). As side note, you might find useful what I did in [this lib (published on maven central)](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-oauth2-test). Most specifically the `@WithOAuth2Login` and `@WithOidcLogin`, even if I don't use much those two myself, as I implement (and test) access control in resource servers, not OAuth2 clients.

Comment: @ch4mp Adding `@Import(VocabularyController::class)` solved the problem! And the missing code you mentioned was simply a code that responded with a status code.

I don't know if you wrote the README.md file for me, but thank you for updating the document and leaving a comment! I will keep an eye on the library you created :)